# How do I stop my conditional from running both the if clause and else clause while inside of a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array I'm looping through to test if a user provided string exists within the loop.  When I run the loop and do the check, it returns true on the array items it matches and false on the ones it doesn't.  I know this is because I'm doing the check on each individual array item.  My question is, how do I only get true if the string matches the array item?

```
var string = "a";
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(string == array[i]){
        console.log("Exists");
    }
    else{
        console.log("Doesn't exist");
    }
}
```

Right now, if I were to run this, I would see:

`"Exists"
"Doesn't exist"
"Doesn't exist"`

Comment: You have to use the break keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using Es6's [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes),

```
var str = "a";
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
var res = arr.includes(str);
if(res) console.log("exists");
```

And if you are concerning about browser support then just use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf),

```
var str = "a";
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
var res = (arr.indexOf(str) > -1);
if(res) console.log("exists");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method

> It's important to note that `.some()` **will stop execution** once it returns the first true value, whereas `.forEach()`and `.filter()` will iterate over the entire array every time. This can have serious performance implications depending on the size of your array.

```
var string = "a";
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];
var exists = array.some(function (elem, index) {
  return string == elem;
});
if (exists) {
  console.log("Exists");
}
else {
  console.log("Doesn't Exist");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
var string = "a";
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];
var found = false;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(string == array[i]){
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (found === true){
    console.log("Exists");
}
else{
    console.log("Doesn't exist");
}
```

Comment: I would add break after the found = true; Otherwise you loop through the entire array even though you found your answer and waste processing time.

Comment: Good point. Edited, but actually indexOf is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to only get matching items:

```
var string = "a";
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];

var matches = array.filter(function(item) {
   return item === string;
});
```

Or ES6

```
var matches = array.filter(item => item === string);
```

You could also use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) if you just want `true`/`false`:

```
array.some(item => item === string); // true
array.some(item => item === 'foo'); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for..of` loop, `break`

```js
var string = "a";
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (let prop of array) {if (prop === string) {console.log("Exists"); break;}};
```